# I can't figure out why my code runs correctly in terminal and eclipse, but not as a jar file by itself

Tags: java, swing

I used html to change the color of the `Buttons` because that was the only way I could change the color of the `Buttons` and keep the color after the `Button` was disabled.
If someone could tell me how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
/*Instance Variables*/
private JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
private JButton button1 = new JButton("");
private JButton button2 = new JButton("");
private JButton button3 = new JButton("");
private JButton button4 = new JButton("");
private JButton button5 = new JButton("");
private JButton button6 = new JButton("");
private JButton button7 = new JButton("");
private JButton button8 = new JButton("");
private JButton button9 = new JButton("");


private String letter = "";
public static int click = 0;
public TicTacToe()
{           
    /*Create Window*/
    window.setSize(300,300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    /*Add Buttons To The Window*/
    window.add(button1);
    window.add(button2);
    window.add(button3);
    window.add(button4);
    window.add(button5);
    window.add(button6);
    window.add(button7);
    window.add(button8);
    window.add(button9);

    /*Add The Action Listener To The Buttons*/
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    button6.addActionListener(this);
    button7.addActionListener(this);
    button8.addActionListener(this);
    button9.addActionListener(this);

    /*Make The Window Visible*/
    window.setVisible(true);

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose Your Letter:   \n1) X\n2) O");
    int let = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if ( input.equals("2")){
          setClick(1);
    }
}

public static void setClick (int cNum){
    click = cNum;            
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {    
    click++;

    /*Calculate Who's Turn It Is*/
    if(click == 1 || click == 3 || click == 5 || click == 7 || click == 9|| click == 11){
        letter = "<html><font color = blue>"+ "X"+"</font></html>";


    } else if(click == 2 || click == 4 || click == 6 || click == 8 || click == 10){

        letter = "<html><font color = red>"+ "O"+"</font></html>";

    }

    /*Display X's or O's on the buttons*/
    if(a.getSource() == button1){

       button1.setText(letter);


        button1.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button2){

        button2.setText(letter);

        button2.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button3){
        button3.setText(letter);

        button3.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button4){

        button4.setText(letter);


         button4.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button5){

        button5.setText(letter);


         button5.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button6){

        button6.setText(letter);


         button6.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button7){

        button7.setText(letter);


         button7.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button8){

        button8.setText(letter);


         button8.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(a.getSource() == button9){


        button9.setText(letter);


         button9.setEnabled(false);
    }     

    Boolean win=null;
  //horizontal wins
    if( button1.getText() == button2.getText() && button2.getText() == button3.getText() && button1.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else if(button4.getText() == button5.getText() && button5.getText() == button6.getText() && button4.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else if(button7.getText() == button8.getText() && button8.getText() == button9.getText() && button7.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }

    //vertical wins
    else if(button1.getText() == button4.getText() && button4.getText() == button7.getText() && button1.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else if(button2.getText() == button5.getText() && button5.getText() == button8.getText() && button2.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else if(button3.getText() == button6.getText() && button6.getText() == button9.getText() && button3.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }

    //diagonal wins
    else if(button1.getText() == button5.getText() && button5.getText() == button9.getText() && button1.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else if(button3.getText() == button5.getText() && button5.getText() == button7.getText() && button3.getText() != "")
    {
    win = true;
    }
    else 
    {
    win = false;
    }

    /*Show a dialog if someone wins or the game is tie*/
    if(win == true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter, "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }  
    else if(click == 9 && win == false&&!(button1.isEnabled()||button2.isEnabled()||button3.isEnabled()||button4.isEnabled()||button5.isEnabled()||button6.isEnabled()||button7.isEnabled()||button8.isEnabled()||button9.isEnabled()))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
        window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
    else if(click==10&&win==false)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
        window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){           
        new TicTacToe();
   }
 }
```

[Project when run in terminal and eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJD8V.png)

[image]

[Project when run as just a .jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWlMJ.png)

[image]

Comment: People are going to keep down voting you and unable to help you until you show us the code

Comment: Ok so I saw the behavior you specified because you're making all the buttons disabled after you click them. This essentially makes them take on the disabled styling which looks grayed out. That's why you're not seeing the colors. Regardless of how I ran it (Eclipse, java -jar, and the jar by itself) I saw the same behavior, I only saw the colors when I changed all the "setEnabled(false)" to "setEnabled(true)"

Comment: I don't get any coloring when I run it in eclipse at the terminal.

Comment: Use the MVC design pattern. Don't disable the button via `setEnabled(false)`, but rather disable the **model** from responding to a button click if the button has already been clicked. Also, learn and use arrays to get rid of all the unnecessary redundancy in your code.

Answer (score 1):

So as I stated in my comment the root cause is the `setEnabled(false)` on the buttons, one way I made the buttons not clickable was by replacing the `setEnabled(false)` with `removeActionListener(this)`. This removes the action listener binding which essentially makes the button take no action when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I honestly don't know why your HTML color rendering functioning is dependent on how you launch your application, but regardless, I suggest tha tyou consider using `setForeground(...)` rather than HTML color rendering, since you know that this will work, and rather than calling `setEnabled(false)` on your button or its Action, use a Model-View-Control or MVC program structure, and rather than de-activate the button, de-activate the **model**. This will also make debugging and enhancing much easier if you wish to do so later. For example, in my code below, the model class has a `press(int row, int col)` method that first checks to see if the grid cell holds an X or O value or if it is blank. If it's not blank, then the method returns/ends. Else it will go on to set the model grid cell's value and change the turn value (whose turn it is).

```
public void press(int row, int col) {
   // if value already selected, ignore 
   if (valueGrid[row][col] != TttValue.BLANK) {
      return;
   }
```

Here's my whole code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class TttMvc {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TttModel model = new TttModel();
      TttView view = new TttView();
      new TttControl(model, view);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TttMvc");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(view);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum TttValue {
   X("X", Color.BLUE), O("O", Color.RED), BLANK("   ", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
   private String text;
   private Color color;

   private TttValue(String text, Color color) {
      this.text = text;
      this.color = color;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }

}
class TttModel {
   public static final int SIDE = 3;
   public static final String GRID_STATE = "grid state";
   public static final String WIN = "win";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
         this);
   private TttValue[][] valueGrid = new TttValue[SIDE][SIDE];
   private TttValue turn = TttValue.X;
   private boolean win = false;

   public TttModel() {
      reset();
   }

   public TttValue getValue(int row, int col) {
      return valueGrid[row][col];
   }

   public void press(int row, int col) {
      // if value already selected, ignore 
      if (valueGrid[row][col] != TttValue.BLANK) {
         return;
      }

      // otherwise set value of cell
      setValueGrid(turn, row, col);

      // TODO: check for win here

      // if not win:
      turn = (turn == TttValue.X) ? TttValue.O : TttValue.X;
   }

   private void setValueGrid(TttValue tttValue, int row, int col) {
      TttValue oldValue = valueGrid[row][col];
      valueGrid[row][col] = tttValue;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(GRID_STATE, oldValue, tttValue);
   }

   public void reset() {
      turn = TttValue.X;
      for (int i = 0; i < valueGrid.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < valueGrid[i].length; j++) {
            setValueGrid(TttValue.BLANK, i, j);
         }
      }      
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name,
         PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name,
         PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
   }
}

class TttView extends JPanel {
   private static final int GAP = 2;
   private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 60);
   private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[TttModel.SIDE][TttModel.SIDE];
   private TttControl control;

   public TttView() {
      JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();

      gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(TttModel.SIDE, TttModel.SIDE, GAP, GAP));
      for (int i = 0; i < buttonGrid.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < buttonGrid[i].length; j++) {
            buttonGrid[i][j] = new JButton(TttValue.BLANK.getText());
            buttonGrid[i][j].setFont(BTN_FONT);
            buttonGrid[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener(i, j));
            gridPanel.add(buttonGrid[i][j]);
         }         
      }

      JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
      resetButton.addActionListener(new ResetListener());

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(resetButton);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   public void setControl(TttControl control) {
      this.control = control;
   }

   private class ResetListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         if (control != null) {
            control.reset();
         }
      }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      private int row;
      private int col;

      public ButtonListener(int row, int col) {
         this.row = row;
         this.col = col;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (control != null) {
            control.press(row, col);
         }
      }
   }

   public void setValue(TttValue tttValue, int row, int col) {
      JButton button = buttonGrid[row][col];
      button.setText(tttValue.getText());
      button.setForeground(tttValue.getColor());
   }

}


class TttControl {
   private TttModel model;
   private TttView view;

   public TttControl(TttModel model, TttView view) {
      this.model = model;
      this.view = view;

      view.setControl(this);
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new ModelListener());
   }

   public void reset() {
      model.reset();
   }

   public void press(int row, int col) {
      model.press(row, col);
   }

   private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (TttModel.GRID_STATE.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            for (int row = 0; row < TttModel.SIDE; row++) {
               for (int col = 0; col < TttModel.SIDE; col++) {
                  TttValue tttValue = model.getValue(row, col);
                  view.setValue(tttValue, row, col);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```